# Is it the same to iterate over Linq expression result than to assign it first to a variable?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, foreach

So, this is more difficult to explain in words, so i will put code examples.
let's suppose i already have a list of clients that i want to filter.

Basically i want to know if this:

```
foreach(var client in list.Where(c=>c.Age > 20))
{
  //Do something
}
```

is the same as this:

```
var filteredClients =  list.Where(c=>c.Age > 20);

foreach(var client in filteredClients)
{
  //Do something
}
```

I've been told that the first approach executes the `.Where()` in every iteration.

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate, i couldn't find any related question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I've been told that the first approach executes the .Where() in every iteration.` Your friends have no idea what they are talking about... Show them this post

Comment: In the SharePoint API looping through for instance a list's Items (i.e. SPList.Items) without first assigning it to a variable DOES execute it each loop. Maybe they  were confusing that with this case ;-)

Comment: See here for an example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb669162(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Colin .Net works same in every environment. Please post the case as a question here if you think differently

Comment: @Eser, in SharePoint, this does work differently, as it will trigger a SQL query each iteration, severely impacting performance:http://apmblog.dynatrace.com/2009/01/11/the-wrong-way-to-iterate-through-sharepoint-splist-items/

Comment: @Colin That is *very* different to OP’s example though.

Comment: @Colin Not a similar case..... `Count` is invoked in every iteration in a **for** loop. Suggested solution is better, but `Count` is still invoked in every iteration. It is faster because the result is already transfered to client... The way how *foreach* works is different than *for*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both those examples are functionally identical. One just stores the result from `Enumerable.Where` in a variable before accessing it while the other just accesses it directly.

To really see why this will not make a difference, you have to understand what a `foreach` loop essentially does. The code in your examples (both of them) is basically equivalent to this (I’ve assumed a known type `Client` here):

```
IEnumerable<Client> x = list.Where(c=>c.Age > 20);

// foreach loop
IEnumerator<Client> enumerator = x.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    Client client = enumerator.Current;
    // Do something
}
```

So what actually happens here is the `IEnumerable` result from the LINQ method is not consumed directly, but an enumerator of it is requested first. And then the foreach loop does nothing else than repeatedly asking for a new object from the enumerator and processing the current element in each loop body.

Looking at this, it doesn’t make sense whether the `x` in the above code is really an `x` (i.e. a previously stored variable), or whether it’s the `list.Where()` call itself. Only the enumerator object—which is created just once—is used in the loop.

---

Now to cover that [SharePoint example](https://web.archive.org/web/20161018012626/http://apmblog.dynatrace.com:80/2009/01/11/the-wrong-way-to-iterate-through-sharepoint-splist-items/) which Colin posted. It looks like this:

```
SPList activeList = SPContext.Current.List;
for (int i=0; i < activeList.Items.Count; i++)
{
    SPListItem listItem = activeList.Items[i];
    // do stuff
}
```

This is a fundamentally different thing though. Since this is not using a `foreach` loop, we do not get that one enumerator object which we use to iterate through the list. Instead, we repeatedly access `activeList.Items`: Once in the loop body to get an item *by index*, and once in the continuation condition of the `for` loop where we get the collection’s `Count` property value.

Unfortunately, Microsoft does not follow its own guidelines all the time, so even if `Items` is a *property* on the [`SPList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ms479015%28v=office.15%29) object, it actually is creating a new [`SPListItemCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ms417004%28v=office.15%29) object every time. And that object is empty by default and will only lazily load the actual items when you first access an item from it. So above code will eventually create a large amount of `SPListItemCollection`s which will each fetch the items from the database. This behavior is also mentioned in the [remarks section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ms479015%28v=office.15%29#Anchor_1) of the property documentation.

This generally violates [Microsoft’s own guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms229054%28v=vs.100%29) on choosing a property vs a method:

> Do use a method, rather than a property, in the following situations.
>
> - The operation returns a different result each time it is called, even if the parameters do not change.

Note that if we used a `foreach` loop for that SharePoint example again, then everything would have been fine, since we would have again only requested a single `SPListItemCollection` and created a single enumerator for it:

```
foreach (SPListItem listItem in activeList.Items.Cast<SPListItem>())
{ … }
```

Comment: Thanks for your well explained and detailed answer @poke. I have one question though: Is it ok if i say that the reason why my two examples are the same is because of the enumerator that's created just once as you mentioned? Does that implement some kind of singleton pattern to accomplish that?

Comment: The enumerator is only created once but not because enumerators are special. If you called `x.GetEnumerator()`, you would get multiple independent enumerator objects. I would rather say that it’s the `foreach` loop that makes your two examples functionally identical since it will just create an enumerator for looping over the collection but does not access the collection itself directly.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

They are not quite the same:

Here is the original C# code:

```
static void ForWithVariable(IEnumerable<Person> clients)
{
    var adults = clients.Where(x => x.Age > 20);
    foreach (var client in adults)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(client.Age.ToString());
    }
}

static void ForWithoutVariable(IEnumerable<Person> clients)
{
    foreach (var client in clients.Where(x => x.Age > 20))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(client.Age.ToString());
    }
}
```

Here is the decompiled Intermediate Language (IL) code this results in (according to [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy)):

```
private static void ForWithVariable(IEnumerable<Person> clients)
{
    Func<Person, bool> arg_21_1;
    if ((arg_21_1 = Program.<>c.<>9__1_0) == null)
    {
        arg_21_1 = (Program.<>c.<>9__1_0 = new Func<Person, bool>(Program.<>c.<>9.<ForWithVariable>b__1_0));
    }
    IEnumerable<Person> enumerable = clients.Where(arg_21_1);
    foreach (Person current in enumerable)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(current.Age.ToString());
    }
}

private static void ForWithoutVariable(IEnumerable<Person> clients)
{
    Func<Person, bool> arg_22_1;
    if ((arg_22_1 = Program.<>c.<>9__2_0) == null)
    {
        arg_22_1 = (Program.<>c.<>9__2_0 = new Func<Person, bool>(Program.<>c.<>9.<ForWithoutVariable>b__2_0));
    }
    foreach (Person current in clients.Where(arg_22_1))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(current.Age.ToString());
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is a key difference:

```
IEnumerable<Person> enumerable = clients.Where(arg_21_1);
```

A more practical question, however, is whether the differences hurt performance. I concocted a test to measure that.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Measure(ForEachWithVariable);
        Measure(ForEachWithoutVariable);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void Measure(Action<List<Person>, List<Person>> action)
    {
        var clients = new[]
        {
            new Person { Age = 10 },
            new Person { Age = 20 },
            new Person { Age = 30 },
        }.ToList();
        var adultClients = new List<Person>();
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for (var i = 0; i < 1E6; i++)
            action(clients, adultClients);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine($"{adultClients.Count} adult clients found");
    }

    static void ForEachWithVariable(List<Person> clients, List<Person> adultClients)
    {
        var adults = clients.Where(x => x.Age > 20);
        foreach (var client in adults)
            adultClients.Add(client);
    }

    static void ForEachWithoutVariable(List<Person> clients, List<Person> adultClients)
    {
        foreach (var client in clients.Where(x => x.Age > 20))
            adultClients.Add(client);
    }
}

class Person
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

After several runs of the program, I was not able to find any significant difference between `ForEachWithVariable` and `ForEachWithoutVariable`. They were always close in time, and neither was consistently faster than the other. Interestingly, if I change `1E6` to just `1000`, the `ForEachWithVariable` is actually consistently *slower*, by about 1 millisecond.

So, I conclude that for **LINQ to Objects**, there is no practical difference. The same type of test could be run if your particular use case involves LINQ to Entities (or SharePoint).

Comment: Note that that isn’t IL but decompiled IL. But your argumentation still holds of course.

Comment: @poke, Thanks, noted. Also, I was just plain wrong. The decompiled IL did have a slight difference.

Comment: Ah, you undeleted the answer :) Btw. as for performance, it’s actually possible and likely that the JIT will optimize the code and remove the temporary variable (since it isn’t used for anything else). And as you already stated, there is no functional difference between those two solutions, so one should just choose what’s more readable :)

Comment: @poke, Definitely agree that readability is far more important unless performance actually turns out to be a problem.